# request.user.is_authenticated stays false after django-allauth social login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

So I am developing a website with django 1.9, python 3.4 and the latest version of django-allauth to allow login through facebook and google.

I have followed all the instructions for installation from the official docs. Using the admin interface I can see the login actually works as new social accounts are added when I log in with my fb and google profiles. I redirect to this dummy view after login:

```
<!-- home.html -->
<html>
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p> your identity has been verified! </p>
{% else %}
<p> not logged in?</p>

{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

but even though the login succeeds and I can see "succesfully logged in through facebook" in the messages when I return to the login view, this view never displays the identity-verified message.

Is there something wrong or is this the normal behavior of django-allauth?

views.py (this is set as the root view):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', context=RequestContext(request))
```

settings.py:

```
# normal working settings...

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

**Edit**

Running through the debugger in views.py I can see that `request.user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser` which explains why `user.is_authenticated` returns false. But why is it still anonymous after succesful login through fb or google?

Comment: Please post your python code for both the auth and this view.

Comment: Added the code for my view. Note that this a brand new test project I started just to make sure this behavior was not due to my actual app. I don't even have models in this project. That is virtually all my code, the rest is from the django-allauth plugin, @LimH.

Comment: @DanielRivas Hi any updates on this?

Comment: I changed machines and could not reproduce the bug. Maybe there was some inconsistencies among my different developing environments? keep you posted if I run into it again @Hosni

Comment: @DanielRivas facing a similar problem on two different machines with  python2.7! I am at complete loss